# test class for trigger apex

Tags: trigger, unit-test

For the below trigger i am unable to pass the condition to get 100 percent code coverage.

trigger:

```
trigger populatePrimaryContact on Contact (after insert, after update) {

    boolean primaryChecked = false;
    //Contact con = null;
    List<Contact> allContacts = null;
    List<Contact> c1 = new List<Contact>();
    List<Contact> updatedList = new List<Contact>();

    c1 = trigger.new;

    Id cRecordType = c1[0].RecordTypeId;
    Id  cid = c1[0].id;

    String Name1 = c1[0].FirstName;
    String Name2 = c1[0].LastName;
    String Name = Name1 + ' ' + Name2;

    String AccountId = c1[0].AccountID;
    String Email = c1[0].Email;
    //String Fax = c1[0].Fax;
    //String Title = c1[0].Title;
    //String Phone = c1[0].Phone;
    boolean PrimaryContact = c1[0].Primary_Contact__c;

   List<RecordType> rtypes = [Select Name, Id From RecordType WHERE sObjectType =: 'Contact' and isActive =: true and Name =: 'PAL Lender Contacts'];

    if(rTypes[0].id == cRecordType){

        allContacts = [Select Name, Account.id, Email, Fax, Title, Primary_Contact__c, Phone from Contact where  Account.id = : AccountId]; 
        if (PrimaryContact){
                for(Contact ac : allContacts){
                        //if (ac.id!=cid){ Prashant(12/04/2012) - Reset Primary Contact flag
                        if (ac.id!=cid && ac.Primary_Contact__c == true){ 
                            ac.Primary_Contact__c = false;
                            updatedList.add(ac);             
                        }
                    update updatedList;
                    }


            Account a = [Select Contact_Name__c,Contact_Email__c,Contact_First_Name__c from Account where id =:  AccountId ];
            a.Contact_Name__c = Name;
            a.Contact_Email__c  = Email ;
            a.Contact_First_Name__c = Name1;
            /*
            a.Contact_Title__c = Title;
            a.Contact_Phone__c = Phone;
            a.Contact_Fax__c = Fax;

            */
            update a;
            }

       }

    }
```

Test method:

```
static testMethod void myUnitTest80() {//Tests new method in CaseTrigger populateDelqServicer
        // Iniitialize data

        System.debug('in myUnitTest80');
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert acc;

        Account acc2 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account2');
        insert acc2;
        RecordType  rtypes = [Select Name, Id From RecordType WHERE sObjectType =: 'Contact' and isActive =: true and Name =: 'PAL Lender Contacts'];
        Contact con1 = new Contact(RecordTypeId = rtypes.id,LastName = 'Test Contact',Master_Policy_Mailing__c=true,Account=acc);
        insert con1;
        Contact con2 = new Contact(RecordTypeId = rtypes.id,LastName = 'Test Contact',Master_Policy_Mailing__c=true,Account=acc);
        insert con2;
        Contact con3 = new Contact(RecordTypeId = rtypes.id,LastName = 'Test Contact',Master_Policy_Mailing__c=true,Account=acc);
        insert con3;
        Contact con4 = new Contact(RecordTypeId = rtypes.id,LastName = 'Test Contact',Master_Policy_Mailing__c=true,Account=acc);
        insert con4;


    }
```

I am not able to pass via the for each loop.

[image]

Comment: Check your debug log may be you are getting any exception.

Comment: trigger is not bulkified, do that first before worrying about test coverage